# drawing circular progress view in iOS

Tags: ios, animation, core-animation

Taking a lot from these questions here: [Problems animating a countdown in swift sprite kit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30289173/problems-animating-a-countdown-in-swift-sprite-kit/30292047), and [Animating circular progress View in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33341794/animating-circular-progress-view-in-swift)

However, the examples above (and all the other examples I've found online) show the progress view animating with a set duration of time. Mine is animating the download progress of a UIImage into a UITableView cell. Here is my code so far. In my UITableViewCell subclass, I have this:

```
func drawProgress(toValue: Float) {
    let circlePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: self.contentView.frame.width / 2, y: self.contentView.frame.height / 2), radius: 30, startAngle: 0, endAngle: 6.28, clockwise: true)
    // create its cooresponding layer
    let circleLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    circleLayer.frame = self.contentView.bounds
    circleLayer.path = circlePath.CGPath
    circleLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
    circleLayer.fillColor = self.contentView.backgroundColor?.CGColor
    circleLayer.lineWidth = 1.0
    self.contentView.layer.addSublayer(circleLayer)

    // create the animation
    let pathAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd")
    pathAnimation.duration = 0.1
    pathAnimation.fromValue = NSNumber(float: 0.0)
    pathAnimation.toValue = NSNumber(float: toValue)

    // apply the animation to path
    circleLayer.addAnimation(pathAnimation, forKey: "strokeEnd")
}
```

I am using NSURLSessionDownloadDelegate to monitor the download progress of the NSData. Inside that method, I get all necessary information to track the download %. Here is my code there:

```
func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, downloadTask: NSURLSessionDownloadTask, didWriteData bytesWritten: Int64, totalBytesWritten: Int64, totalBytesExpectedToWrite: Int64) {

  //...other code above to get the correct cell for index path, etc
  myCell.drawProgress(toValue:download.progress)
  //trackCell.progressView.progress = download.progress
 }
```

The commented out line:

```
 //myCell.progressView.progress = download.progress
```

is a UIProgressBar. This UIProgressBar reports and shows in the cell the correct progress every time, so I know that I have all the necessary info, and the info is correct, so it's just something about how I am implementing this to make it not work. Currently, when I load the tableView, I can see the first few cells draw out the animation really quickly (faster than the actual download), and then when I scroll down the tableView, all the progress bars are already full, and i don't see any animation in them.

I know that download.progress contains the correct float that is tracking the download process. How can I get this CAShapeLayer to correctly animate for each cell?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
var progressCircle = CAShapeLayer()

// computed property - set() property observer updates circle when passed new progress value
var progress: CGFloat {
    get {
        return progressCircle.strokeEnd
    }
    set {
        if (newValue >= 1) {
            progressCircle.strokeEnd = 1
        } else if (newValue < 0) {
            progressCircle.strokeEnd = 0
        } else {
            progressCircle.strokeEnd = newValue
        }
    }
}
```

To Use - set up your progress circle object

```
func createProgressCircle() {
    let rotationTransform = CATransform3DRotate(CATransform3DIdentity, CGFloat(-M_PI_2), 0, 0, 1.0)

    // you can either create a rect for the circle now programmatically
     //or pass in the frame of an existing storyboard object to draw within
    let rectForCircle = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(myView.origin), size: CGSize(width: myView.width, height: myView.height))
    progressCircle.path = circlePath(inRect: rectForCircle).cgPath

    progressCircle.lineWidth = 4.0
    progressCircle.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    progressCircle.strokeColor = sitchRed.cgColor
    progressCircle.transform = rotationTransform
    circleShapeView.layer.addSublayer(progressCircle)
    circleShapeView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear // make sure the circleView is clear so underlayer circle shape can show through
    progress = 0.0
}
```

To show progress changes, pass the current progress value of your download into to progress property in your viewController, and the set() property observer will update the current stroke position of the circle :)